# How to use external search box with jQuery DataTables

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am building a simple browse document page. For my tables I've exported the dataTables template (New to using templates) but I would like the search bar `(Class=search2)` to be placed where the `"keyword"` search box is instead of it's standard area.

But every time I move search box class `"search2"` to replace `"keyword"` it does not connect to the data table!

Could you please give me advice on how to do this?

As well as why there seems to be two of everything on my page (search2 and filters)?

You can find the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/judison/gbwpgj0r/).

**HTML Code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets\table.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.table').dataTable();
   });

</script>


<body>

<div align="center">
<br><br>

<div id="table" class="outsideBorder" align="left">
<div style="font-size:large; margin:20px;" align="left"> Browse Documents</div>
<div style="font-size:x-small; margin-left:20px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:5px;" align="left"> Keyword</div>
<div style="float:left; width:80%; "><input style=" width:100%; margin-left:20px; height:26px;" type="text" class="keywords outsideBorderSearch"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; "><button style="color:white; margin-left:10px; background-color:#f29030; border:none; height:26px;" type="button">SEARCH</button> </div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%; margin-left:20px; font-size:x-small; margin-top:20px;">Type
<br><br>
<select style="width:62%">
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%; margin-left:10px; font-size:x-small; margin-top:20px;">Case/CYP
<br><br>
<select style="width:62%">
   <option value="CASE">CASE</option>
   <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%; margin-left:10px; font-size:x-small; margin-top:20px;">Time
<br><br>
<select style="width:102%">
   <option value="LAST MONTH">LAST MONTH</option>
   <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<br><br><br><br><br>
</div></div>
<div class="wrap">       
   <div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="dataTables_length" id="DataTables_Table_0_length"><label>Show <select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" class=""><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div><div id="DataTables_Table_0_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="search2" placeholder="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0"></label></div><table class="table table-hover dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">

<thead>
  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=" Type : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 60px;"> Type </th><th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 69px;">Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 168px;">Date</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Details: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 97px;">Details</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class=""><img src="http://cdn.toptenreviews.com/rev/misc/articles/7805/top-10-excel-ti-1.png" width="10"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>Excel</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class=""><img src="http://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/PowerPoint.png" width="10"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>PowerPoint</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class=""><img src="http://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/PowerPoint.png" width="10"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
    <td>PowerPoint</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class=""><img src="http://www.lb5.uscourts.gov/img/icons/icon-doc.png" width="10"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Doe</td>
    <td>11-09-15</td>
    <td>Doc</td>

  </tr></tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries</div><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate"><a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">Previous</a><span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></span><a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">Next</a></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.outsideBorder{
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color: #cccccc;
width:580px;
height:100%;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}

.outsideBorderSearch{

border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color: #cccccc;
width:600px;
height:300px;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}


.random{

}

.wrap{
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color: #cccccc;
   width:580px;
   padding:20px;
   margin-top:30px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }



footer a {
 color: #cccccc;
 padding-left: 10px;
 }

 footer img { 
 height:45px;
 width:45px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 }


 form {
  float:right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
 }

 .table img {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   margin-left:15px;
 }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/external.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use the following code where `.outsideBorderSearch` is the selector for external search box and `.table` is the selector for the table.

```
$('.outsideBorderSearch').on( 'keyup click', function () {
   $('.table').DataTable().search(
       $('.outsideBorderSearch').val()
   ).draw();
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbwpgj0r/1/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

You had two duplicate DataTables controls because of the invalid markup, most likely you copied/pasted HTML from dynamically generated content. You need to use simple HTML according to the requirements as noted in the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great, I didn't see a manual before so thank you for linking it again :)